# Using CcontrolsFX's SpreadsheetView in Java 9

Tags: javafx, java-9, controlsfx, javafx-9

I've got an application written in Java 8 with ControlsFX 8.40.14.

I run the app under Java 9 (jdk-9.0.1 to be precise) and I got the following exception when the app tries to display SpreadsheetView component.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.impl_setReorderable(Z)V
    at org.controlsfx.control.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetView.getTableColumn(SpreadsheetView.java:2216)
    at org.controlsfx.control.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetView.setGrid(SpreadsheetView.java:1162)
    at org.controlsfx.control.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetView.<init>(SpreadsheetView.java:563)
    at org.controlsfx.control.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetView.<init>(SpreadsheetView.java:475)
    (...)javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3589)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8300(Scene.java:3517)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3885)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Scene.java:3604)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2613)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

The same exception occurs when the app is compiled with jdk1.8.144 and jdk-9.0.1

I cannot migrate to ControlsFX 9.0.0 as they [don't support SpreadsheetView](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/780/controlsfx-should-support-java-9#comment-40046998) yet.

Any idea how to run such an application in Java 9?

Comment: I believe the issue here is that the API is actually changed and the impl_setReorderable is now public in Java 9 - setReorderable()  and is not longer called impl_setReorderable() - so you need to either run on JDK 8, or upgrade to ControlsFX 9

Comment: Just to let you know that I will take some time to migrate the SpreadsheetView toward JDK9. Lots of SpreadsheetView features have been removed from JDK9 and I don't know how to bypass these. Thus the fact it's not working in JDK9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this may be late but a lot of controlsfx components do not work on JDK 9 because of couple of reasons, a lot of controlsfx components were not compatible with JDK 9,, thus version 9 was released to migrate from JDK 8 to 9,,, however, SpreadSheetView is removed...

check this issue: https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/780/controlsfx-should-support-java-9

as kerry said, used JDK 8

Comment: It's an old thread, but just for reference. ControlsFX migrated from bitbucket.org to github: https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx
Here's the link to migrated issue mentioned above: https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/971

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the first line of the error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.impl_setReorderable(Z)V
```

The method `TableColumn.imp_setReorderable()` I suspect is an internal and undocumented method? Possibly it has been removed in the JDK you are using (1.8.144).

I notice from the manifest for ControlsFX that version 8.40.14 was built with JDK1.8.0_131.

You could try obtaining JDK 1.8.0_131 and try running your application with that?

Comment: I also suspect that the method TableColumn.imp_setReorderable()  is an internal and undocumented method and was changed/removed but in Java 9. And that causes my problem. I still can't run the app under Java 9 so I guess I need to wait until ControlsFX will be adjusted to follow the changes.

Comment: I don't get what is the point in checking with 1.8.0_131.
The app **works** in 1.8.0_144 (compiled and run) and I don't understand what would running in 1.8.0_131 prove. The problem only occurs when running in 9.0.1 (doesn't matter if compiled with JDK 9 or JDK 8)

Comment: Your question says `The same exception occurs when the app is compiled with jdk1.8.144`.

Comment: That's right. Compiled with jdk1.8.144 but still running with Java 9.